# Connect to Google BigQuery in R using Simba JDBC driver

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery

I cannot connect to my Google Bigquery dataset via Simba JDBC driver. 
I want to connect from R application using RJDBC package.  I set the parameters as follows:

```
library(RJDBC)

driver <- JDBC(driverClass = "com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc42.Driver", classPath = "~/JDBC/GoogleBigQueryJDBC42.jar", identifier.quote = "'")

conn <- dbConnect(driver,"jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=My_project_Id;OAuthType=1;")
```

but I receive an error saying:

```
Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: if it's R, why not use https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I should have add required libraries to Java class-path. So in R I executed the following commands:

```
 .jaddClassPath("jackson-core-2.1.3.jar")
 .jaddClassPath("google-oauth-client-1.22.0.jar")
 .jaddClassPath("google-http-client-jackson2-1.22.0.jar")
 .jaddClassPath("google-http-client-1.22.0.jar")
 .jaddClassPath("GoogleBigQueryJDBC41.jar")
 .jaddClassPath("google-api-services-bigquery-v2-rev320-1.22.0.jar")
 .jaddClassPath("google-api-client-1.22.0.jar")
```